# How to change the object that is referenced by a variable?

Tags: python

I have an array of objects. I am interested in writing a function that will find a specific object in a list and return a reference to it.

Imagine the following code snippet was possible:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
def find(q):
    return q[0]
a = find(list1) 
a = 0 # This should change the object that "a" is referencing to.
print list1 # [0, 2, 3] is desired as result.
```

It is easy to do with pointers in C++, but how can I do it in python?

Comment: Are they actually objects, or immutable types (int, str)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve exact same semantics may not be possible but something similar can be achieved by a proxy with get/set methods, though I am not clear exactly what and why you needed this, so final solution could be much more complex or simple, anyway here is my solution

```
def find(q):
    return Pointer(q, 0)

class Pointer(object):
    def __init__(self, alist, index):
        self.alist = alist
        self.index = index

    def get(self):
        return self.alist[self.index]

    def set(self, value):
        self.alist[self.index] = value

list1 = [1, 2, 3]     
p = find(list1)
p.set(0)
print list1
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I was about to post more or less the same... you were quicker. +1

Comment: Note that this is only required for immutable types (e.g. `int`).  If the items in the list are instances of a mutable type (e.g. a user-defined class), then this proxy thing is unnecessary.

Comment: Nice. Unfortunately, it won't work if the object changes position in the list between the `find` and the dereference, as the OP indicated in a comment to a now-deleted question.

Comment: @AndréCaron why? if you want to assign a new object to an index of the list you need the wrapper class too?!

Comment: @FredLarson if list changes , is sorted or deleted etc than bets way would be to have each element has proxy at first place

Comment: @AnuragUniyal I agree with your last statement. And that is what I am going to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Function currying is one way to get an effect similar to by-reference semantics:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]

def accessor(alist, index, value=None):
    if value is not None:
        alist[index] = value
    return alist[index]

def find(q):
    def access_first(value=None):
        return accessor(q, 0, value)
    return access_first

a = find(list1) 
print a() # This access the value that "a" references.
print a(0) # This changes the object that "a" is referencing to and returns its value.
print list1 # [0, 2, 3] is result.
```

The output:

```
1
0
[0, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Is this really function currying...? +1 for a solid approach though.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the solution to be more of a true curry - and more flexible too.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, because numeric objects are immutable in Python.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve what I described?

Comment: It depends. The answer BenH gave might work for you. If your real code deals with mutable objects something similar to the original code you posted would be fine (because variables are actually references in Python). Just remember that the `=` operator reassigns the reference, not the referent. You'd have to call a mutating function on the object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability. If `find` returns a list, you still can't use it to make `list[0]` refer to a different object (though you can mutate that object). You're confusing the values of variables, collection items, etc. (references) with the objects referred to.

Comment: @delnan: I disagree that it has nothing to do with immutability. The OP wants to return a C++-style reference that can be used to modify the referent. The example shows integers, and this is not possible because they are immutable. Of course, another issue is that the assignment operator changes the reference, and calling a mutating function on the object would be required to change its state.

Comment: Remember, even with references or pointers you'd still have a (C++) reference or pointer *to a location* where a perfectly mutable (Python) reference lies. Nobody talks about mutating the object itself or  replacing it with another object. You could take a pointer to where the list stores its first item (that item is, of course, a reference), and change the reference there to refer to another object.